# Extract CI-values from ci.AUC function

Tags: r

I am calculating confidence interval from a AUC prediction. I want to extract the CI values and paste CI: infront, however, my solution does not work.

```
 data <- c(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0)
 pred <- c(1.05139877586338, 0.178798168643069, -3.69764655785213, 1.38607788593773, 
 -0.781109023131622, -1.85468845523379)

paste("CI:", round(ci.cvAUC(data,pred  = pred)$ci),2)
```

gives this:

```
"CI: 0.71" "CI: 0.89"
```

I would like:

```
CI: 0.71-0.89
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `paste` around `ci.cvAUC` to collapse the outcome into one string. Try :

```
paste("CI:", paste(round(ci.cvAUC(data,pred  = pred)$ci,2), collapse = '-'))
```

Or with `sprintf` :

```
sprintf('CI: %s', paste(round(ci.cvAUC(data,pred  = pred)$ci,2), collapse = '-'))
```